# Change TrayIcon Tooltip from ProgressMonitorDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am using the Eclipse RCP trayitem, which is described **[in Vogellas tutorials](http://www.vogella.de/articles/RichClientPlatform/article.html#systemtray)**.

The requirement now is not only to show the name of the app in the tooltip but also a percentage while doing lengthy operations.

I understand that the trayitem attribute is a private from `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor`, so I added a getter and setter method.

The only thing missing is a possibility to access the trayitem instance from my `ProgressMonitorDialog` instance.

Can you tell me, how you would solve this puzzle?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can build a `TrayItem` around the `SystemTray` from any windows:

```
final Tray tray = window.getShell().getDisplay().getSystemTray();
TrayItem trayItem = new TrayItem(tray, SWT.NONE);
```

, do you have to access *that* `TrayItem` instance from `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor`?

You could put it in a more accessible class or even build one where  and when you need it.

---

Speaking of showing percentage while doing lengthy operations, I just wanted to mentioned the latest tasks icons [improvements in Eclipse3.6M6](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M6-201003121448/eclipse-news-M6.html) (not system tray, but related at they now can provide a good status indicator). See [Snippet 336](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet336.java?view=co) for an example.

- TaskItem overlay image

> The new API `TaskItem#setOverlayImage(Image)` allows clients to set an image to be displayed on top of the application button in the taskbar.

[alt text http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M6-201003121448/images/overlayimage.png](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M6-201003121448/images/overlayimage.png)

- TaskItem overlay text

> The new API `TaskItem#setOverlayText(String)` allows clients to set a short text to be displayed on top of the application button in the taskbar.

[alt text http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M6-201003121448/images/overlaytext.png](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M6-201003121448/images/overlaytext.png)

- TaskItem progress

> The new APIs `TaskItem#setProgress(int)` and `TaskItem#setProgressState(int)` allows clients to show progress indication in the application button in the taskbar.

[alt text http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M6-201003121448/images/progress.png](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M6-201003121448/images/progress.png)

Comment: Thanks! As far as I know within the ProgressMonitorDialog class/thread I have no display or window access....I tried also to open a messagebox with this class and it failed because of this. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Raven: I don't understand: a `Dialog` is a `Window`. the `getShell()` method should be available.

Comment: Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
Thats the errormessage i get, after accessing the shell/display.
I am using the ProgressDialog from this tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJobs/article.html

Comment: @Raven, off course, you need to do it within the GUI Thread. See for instance http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg16800.html

Comment: Yes, this works, just I get two trayicons now :-(. The one which was already there plus the one in the lengthy operation. I thought getTrayIcon() would get the ONE and not create another one...

Comment: @Raven: true, that is an issue. You could try and find a way to store "globally" the first `TrayItem` created by `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` (through some kind of resources accessible through the shell). The idea remains: access to that `TrayItem` within the GUI thread.